# Using different SSL context for Rest & Soap & JDBC in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, hsm, sslcontext

Using spring boot right now with hsm & mssql jdbc & rest & soap services running in one single microservice.

**MainApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    @Autowired
    public Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * init keystores
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void keystoresInit() {       
        logger.info("Starting keystores Init");

            // INIT Keystore - soap service
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(env.getProperty("keyserver.ssl.key-store-type"));
            ksFile = new FileInputStream(env.getProperty("keyserver.ssl.key-store"));
            ks.load(ksFile, pass);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(ks, pass);

            // INIT Truststore
            KeyStore trustKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance(env.getProperty("cacert.ssl.key-store-type"));
            tsFile = new FileInputStream(env.getProperty("cacert.ssl.key-store"));
            trustKeystore.load(tsFile, env.getProperty("cacert.ssl.key-store-password").toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(trustKeystore);

            // INIT SSLContext
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
            SSLContext.setDefault(context);

            Map<String, String> samplekeys = new HashMap<String, String>();


            CustomSSLContext cssc = CustomSSLContext.getInstance(); //which is used for soap services
            cssc.initSSLContexts(env.getProperty("keyserver.ssl.key-store"),
                    env.getProperty("keyserver.ssl.key-store-type"), pass, samplekeys);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            --
        } finally {
            --
        }

    }

    /**
     * Configuring Hikari datasource and setting password from vault.
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.hikari")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource ds = null;
        try {
            password = getting from vault;
            ds = new HikariDataSource();
            ds.setPassword(new String(password));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            --
        } finally {
            --
        }
        return ds;
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
keyserver:
  ssl:
    key-store: sample.keystore
    key-store-type: Luna

cacert:
  ssl:
    key-store: cacerts #same cacerts placed in running JDK instance as well
    key-store-password: samplepass
    key-store-type: jks
```

**java.security**

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=com.safenetinc.luna.provider.LunaProvider
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
..etc
```

**Problem:**

1. Postcontruct method has the keystore & truststore initialized, all
   the connections use the LunaProvider which i configured in
   java.security file listed as 3rd item (security provider). This ssl
   connections used by SOAP calls. This works well.
2. The database bean also uses same lunaprovider which i dont want to work in that ssl. because it causes so many problems. i need to
   use different ssl context for database so that i works parallel. how
   do i do that.
3. I have rest calls incoming & outgoing from this service. wanted to know if can use another ssl context for that? without touching
   lunaprovider?

Thanks in advance.